# Different applications to the same database

Tags: java, c#, sql-server, web-services

I have 3 different applications

1. ASP.NET web application
2. Java Desktop application
3. Android Studio mobile application

These 3 applications have the same database and and they need to connect from any part of the world with an internet connection. They share almost all the information, so, if you move something in one application it has to update the information in the other 2 applications.

I have the database on a physical server and I want to know how best to make this connection.

I have searched but I couldn't find if I have to connect directly to the server with some SQL Server, using Web Service, or something like that.

I hope someone could help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to first create a Web API layer (REST/SOAP) that will be used to perform all the relative operations in the centralized DB. Once that is setup, any of your applications written in any language can use the exposed web API methods to manipulate the data of the same DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a global solution - will you have multiple copies of the applications in different parts of the world as well?

In this scenario you should be looking at a cloud-hosted database with some form of geo-replication so that you can keep latency to a minimum.

There are no restrictions on the number of applications that can connect to a specific database - you do not have to create a different database for each and you may be able to reuse Stored Procedures between applications if they perform the same task.

I would however look at the concept of schemas - any database objects that are specific to one app should be separated from other - so put them in a schema for "App1". Shared objects can be in a shared schema.